# Row wise iteration with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have a data frame and I want to generate a new column that has the result of an calculation based on the row before. Additionally the calculation has some conditions.

The data frame consist of **energy production = p, energy consumption = c, energy grid = g, energy safe = s**

My goal is to calculate the usage of a battery in a PV-System. When the modules produces more then needed the battery gets loaded and otherwise unloaded. When the batterie don't have enough energy the grid delivers the remainig energy.

So in the first line the batterie gets loaded because I produce more than I need. In the 5 line I need more energy than I produce, so the batterie gets unloaded and so on.

One row is one hour. So n+1 is based on the energy demand and supply of n.

```
### Old:  
n p c g  
1 2 1 0  
2 3 1 0  
3 4 3 0
4 3 5 2  
5 5 8 3  
6 2 1 0
```

```
### New:  
n p c g s  
1 2 1 0 1  
2 3 1 0 3  
3 4 3 0 4  
4 3 5 0 2  
5 5 8 1 0  
6 2 1 0 1
```

When i use your code the result is like this:

[image: PV_Battery-Load-Unload]

First column - c
Second Colum - p
Third colum - g
Fourth colum - s

The battery gets loaded but the unload process does not fit from what is   expected. The battery has 2.3801 energy and the demand in n+1 is 0.875.

So the result should be 2.3801 - 0.875 = 1.5015
This process should end when s = 0

I dont understand why your codes works for the rest of data.

Comment: Please check it again.  In my console, I am getting correct results.

Comment: is it possible that the structure(list) function has an impact on this. My data table is loaded as read_csv???

Comment: Shouldn't be, but give me some time, I'll give you some alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636052/calculate-cumulative-sum-cumsum-floored-at-zero) which works very well for my problem.

My battery is floored at 0 and limited to 16 kWh, so I added just the pmin function.

```
mutate(result = accumulate(production-consumw1, ~ pmin(16,pmax(0, .x + .y)), .init = 0)[-1])
```

Thanks for your help!